# How to make a variable on the place of a button?

Tags: xcode, variables, button, applescript

I have this game with so many code, but most of it is over and over repeating of the same void with just one button in difference.

I simplified the code for this purpose:

```
-(void)button1Action {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(button1.frame, image1.frame)) {
        //button 1 is used a few times between these two brackets
    }
}
-(void)button2Action {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(button2.frame, image1.frame)) {
        //button 2 is used a few times between these two brackets
    }
}
-(void)button3Action {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(button3.frame, image1.frame)) {
        //button 3 is used a few times between these two brackets
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to make one void with something like this?:

```
-(void)buttonXAction {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(buttonX.frame, image1.frame)) {
        //button X is used a few times between these two brackets
    }
}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a method like this:

```
- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender {

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sender.frame, image1.frame)) {

        //This will perform the action on what ever buttons calls the method. 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess this is the thing I need! But how to declare what sender is in this case?

Comment: you can add the action to every button like so: [button1 addTarget:self
               action:@selector(buttonAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: Do that for every button, and they will become the "sender" argument. This will execute the code for every button that calls the method.

Comment: I don't think this is really what I'm looking for. This piece of code isn't about pressing one of the buttons. It could also be image1,2,3. I am working with an object somewehere else in the code and sometimes I refer to a void. The void depends on the button I'm working with. In that void I will do stuff with that button. 
So what I need is a void with a variable for image or button 1,2,3 which is declared in the code which is in that place somewhere else...
Understand? =s

Comment: This code does what you originally asked for. You can manipulate more than just the button inside the method you just have to implement it within the scope of the method. In any case good luck.